# Cloud Flare Certificate - Origin server NET::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID

Tags: ssl, cloudflare, docker-registry

I've a private container registry, thats exposed with a dns proxied with CloudFlare.
So far everything was working fine, now we are migrating our services devops to github actions and while I try to publish the image to the registry, I got an error 413, too long. And it makes sense, because a docker image can have more then 100MB which is the limit of CloudFlare uploads, in free tier.

If I try to run the docker commands by hand, everything works ok, I think it's related in how the commands work under the hood.

I've thought about upgrading my plan, but unfortunately it's too expansive for us now.
So in order to solve it, I thought about requesting origin server certificate from CloudFlare and remove the proxy from it.

So far I've done the following steps

- Enabled full ssl type
- Create a custom edge certificate
- Create an origin certificate
- Copied the certificate.pem and key to my server
- Copied the root certificate from CloudFlare
- Created a fullchain.pem with certificate.pem and ca.pem
- Used in nginx.

But when I try to access it, I got NET::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID

Do you have any suggestions? Did I understood wrong how the certificate should work?

Comment: Can you please provide more details which commands you exactly used. Why don't you get an container registry in Azure or something like that?